# How to get ping statistic with C#?

Tags: c#, ping

How to get ping statistic from C#?

I can ping from CMD

I can also ping from C#

[image]

```
        var uri = "google.com";
        var pingResult = new Ping().Send(uri);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping(v=vs.110).aspx

But in ping result I cannot find Ping statistic, Approximate round trip, Minimum, Maximum.
There is some data but not everything.

Comment: What is that `Ping` class? Where does it come from?

Comment: @s.m. Built-in class.

Comment: There's the [approximate round trip time](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.pingreply.roundtriptime(v=vs.110).aspx). That's the furthest you'll get

Comment: All the data you're looking for appears to be there.  You just have to execute multiple pings and calculate the results to your needs.  What calculations have you tried and where are you stuck?  Are you just asking how to calculate an average given a series of numbers?

Comment: @s.m https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @David I did not know that I should execute few times. Math is not problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's the [approximate round trip time](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.pingreply.roundtriptime(v=vs.110).aspx) in the `PingReply` class. You can use that to get the round trip. To get the maximum, minimum and average just send multiple packets and do.. math on them. That's exactly what the `ping` command does as well, it sent 4 packets and calculated the min max and average of the sum of those packets.

Answer (score 0):

Check [MSDN doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.pingreply(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
        Ping pingSender = new Ping ();
        PingOptions options = new PingOptions ();

        // Use the default Ttl value which is 128,
        // but change the fragmentation behavior.
        options.DontFragment = true;

        // Create a buffer of 32 bytes of data to be transmitted.
        string data = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes (data);
        int timeout = 120;
        PingReply reply = pingSender.Send (args[0], timeout, buffer, options);
        if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
        {
            //Here you get all your stats.

            Console.WriteLine ("Address: {0}", reply.Address.ToString ());
            Console.WriteLine ("RoundTrip time: {0}", reply.RoundtripTime);
            Console.WriteLine ("Time to live: {0}", reply.Options.Ttl);
            Console.WriteLine ("Don't fragment: {0}", reply.Options.DontFragment);
            Console.WriteLine ("Buffer size: {0}", reply.Buffer.Length);
        }
```